# Change os.name for run-time App

Tags: java, windows-runtime, jvm

My app was coded to check for OS being used, ex:

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_XP
```

I'm trying to run the app on Windows version that is not specified in the code, thus getting an error.
Is there anyway I can change JVM's property "os.name" to avoid this run-time error?

Thank you!

Comment: what is your windows version, what error are you getting?

Comment: It's win2003 server that I'm using, and the error is just a customized throw statement to abort the App.

Comment: Is recompiling the code to fix the check not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, code change is not an option :( the users are expecting to run the App asap and QA/Deployment take too long.